# How to highlight file without mouse after ctrl + down

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

How do I highlight a file, skip to another file in the folder, and highlight it also, without using the mouse?

Example, how do I select the file called "3 - SelectFoo.txt"

[image]

Comment: The selector is the spacebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Select the first one and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

2-  Without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> move the cursor with the arrow keys, a rectangle (selector) will be seen

3 - When the selector is over the file, press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>.

You can continue selecting files as long as you don't release  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.